# PHP & MySql: How to Populate PHP dropdown list from a MySql table?

Tags: php, mysql

It seems I'm having troubles populating a dropdown list from a MySql table.

The connection to the database works, and I can write data to the table.  I can also display data in each field on the screen.

I would like to be able to populate a dropdown list from a column in this table.  I've searched this forum and have not been able to incorporate some of the ideas presented.

I'm hoping someone may have this knowledge.

Thanks in advance,
Ken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of writing to a table, use a `<select> <option..>` combos to have the dropdown.

```
echo "<select name='something'>";
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $query_result ) ) {
  echo "<option value='$row[val]'>$row[data]</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

ofcourse, it may change depending on your fields.

Comment: So, my field name is "Province_State", would I replace that in the [data]

Comment: you'll use `$row[Province_State]`. :)